# Flutter Item ExpansionPanelList doesn't change state

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to retrieve data from API, that's works nice.

After that I want to show my data in a ExpansionPanelList, which is builded by a method:

```
class _CartaPageState extends State<CartaPage> {

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Nos suscribimos al provider
    final productoService = Provider.of<ProductoService>(context);
    final List<Producto> productos = productoService.productos; 
    _productosItems = productosToItem(productos);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ExpansionPanelList(
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
                setState(() {
                  _productosItems[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                  //productosItems[index].isExpanded = !productosItems[index].isExpanded;
                });
              },
              //children: productosToItem(productoService.entrantes).map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
              children: _productosItems.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
                return ExpansionPanel(
                  headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(item.headerValue),
                    );
                  },
      ................
```

The data is shown perfect, but the state is not **refreshing** on my ItemModel, I think the problem is because the widget is redrawing each time I touch the panel list, that retrieve (again) data from the API and never changes the state.

How can I resolve it?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: CartaPage is wraped by:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ProductoService()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Material App',
        home: CartaPage()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I agree I am losing state, this it the method to convert **Product** to **Item**:

```
List<Item> productosToItem(List<Producto> productos) {
  return List.generate(productos.length, (index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: productos[index].tipo,
      expandedValue: productos[index].nombre,
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `ExpansionPanel` having its `isExpanded` set to `item.isExpanded`?

You get your `isExpanded` state from whatever `productosToItem()` generates.

When you call `setState` you queue a new build, which will call `productosToItem()` again. Without knowing what that method does, I cannot help much.

I would suggest you look into `productosToItem` and why it isn't setting `isExpanded` to the correct value.

If `_productosItems[index].isExpanded` isn't a setter, I would imagine you are losing the state.

EDIT 1:

You can create an internal state list that can persist the expanded state:

```
class Item {
  Item({
    this.expandedValue,
    this.headerValue,
    this.producto,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  Producto producto; // <------------- ADDED
  bool isExpanded;
}

class _CartaPageState extends State<CartaPage> {
  Map<Producto, bool> expanded = {}; // <------------- ADDED

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Nos suscribimos al provider
    final productoService = Provider.of<ProductoService>(context);
    final List<Producto> productos = productoService.productos;
    // NOTE: ----------- converted to a local variable
    final _productosItems = productosToItem(productos);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ExpansionPanelList(
              key: ValueKey(productos.length),  // <------------- ADDED
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
                // NOTE: ----------- updated
                final producto = productos[index];
                setState(() {
                  expanded[producto] = !isExpanded;
                });
              },
              children: _productosItems.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
                return ExpansionPanel(
                  isExpanded: expanded[item.producto], // <------------- ADDED
                  canTapOnHeader: true,
                  headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(item.headerValue),
                    );
                  },
                  body: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.expandedValue),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Item> productosToItem(List<Producto> productos) {
    // keep a list of previous map
    final toRemove = Map<Producto, bool>.from(expanded);
    final items = List.generate(productos.length, (index) {
      final producto = productos[index];
      // set initial expanded state
      expanded.putIfAbsent(producto, () => false);
      // the item will be retained
      toRemove.remove(producto);
      return Item(
        headerValue: producto.tipo,
        expandedValue: producto.nombre,
        producto: producto,
        isExpanded: expanded[producto],
      );
    });
    if (toRemove.isNotEmpty) {
      // cleanup unused items
      expanded.removeWhere((key, _) => toRemove.containsKey(key));
    }
    return items;
  }
}
```

The `key: ValueKey(productos.length),` is needed, since `ExpansionPanelList` acted weirdly with magically appearing or disappearing items.

Comment: added new info. I agree with you about losing the state, but I don't know how can I retrive my products, convert them to Item and finally show the data and change state. I don't know. Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to persist the expanded state throughout the app, but only while this widget is alive (a.k.a showing), then simply create an internal state that holds the expanded state only. Otherwise you will have to add some method to, say `productoService` to change `productos[index].nombre`.

Comment: would you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Added an edit with a working example how to hold a local state of the currently expanded items.